# GET request doesn't return anything, api route mismatch

Tags: reactjs, rest, asp.net-core

I have an issue with this controller, I send a request to

```
https://localhost:44490/api/Concert/GetPartyConcerts
```

But I receive:

```
router.ts:11 No routes matched location "/api/Concert/GetPartyConcerts"
```

My controller looks like this:

```
 [ApiController]
    public class ConcertController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IPartyConcertRepository _partyConcertRepository;

        public ConcertController(IPartyConcertRepository partyConcertRepository)
        {
            _partyConcertRepository = partyConcertRepository;
        }
        [HttpGet("GetPartyConcerts")]
        [ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(IEnumerable<Party>))]
        public IActionResult GetPartyConcerts()
        {
            var partyConcerts = _partyConcertRepository.GetParties();

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);

            return Ok(partyConcerts);
        }
    }
```

I tried using postman, and I've sent the request to:

```
http://localhost:44490/api/Concert/GetPartyConcerts
```

It returned me this error:

```
GET http://localhost:44490/api/Concert/GetPartyConcerts
Error: socket hang up
Request Headers
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.31.1
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: f3acfa04-0801-4575-b0bd-f4530729fb2d
Host: localhost:44490
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
```

**Answer:**
The issue was with the url, here is the trouble shooting guide:

1. Check whether you use http or https
2. Check your port(in the case of postman check it in the *launchSettings.json*)
3. Check the path to your controller

**To avoid this completely(short answer):**

Use swagger

**Guide for configuring swagger in ASP .NET WEB API:**

1. Go to `Properties -> launchSettings.json`
2. Find the *ISS EXPRESS* section
3. Configure it how you like, or use my example

**Example:**

```
"TestWebApplication": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7194;http://localhost:5013",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you correctly configured the base route for the concert controller? Unless you’re using convention based configuration I don’t see an attribute specifying the controller route in your code.

Comment: I added the route attribute based on @RukaiFeng answer, but the error still persists.

Comment: If you have configured Swagger, make use of that to see the routes for your endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to visit  endpoints in ConcertController  with the uri like

```
https://localhost:44490/api/Concert/GetPartyConcerts
```

you have to add`[Route("api/[controller]")]`  attribute

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ConcertController : ControllerBase
```

Comment: I added the Route attribute, but the error still persists

Comment: @koogel, also check the http scheme,http/https

Comment: your first uri start with https but in postman you tried with http,which do you really want?

Comment: Ok, postman now returns an html, but it doesn't return the list of concerts, it returns: You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.

Comment: Do you mean you receive You need to enable JavaScript to run this app  with react api calls ? By the way If you try with  postman ,it should return the list of concerts in json format

Comment: If you got the error with react api calls,you'd better modify your question and update what you've tried

Comment: Added the html document returned by postman

Comment: I agree, postman should return the list of concerts in json format, yet I receive this html document. I added some breakpoints for the controller calls, and when I enter the page its blank, the dev tools show me the same warning: No routes matched location "/api/Concert/GetPartyConcerts"